# TinyMCE - how to remove controls that appear when you select a word or a phrase

Tags: jquery, css, tinymce

When I click a word or a phrase, TinyMCE shows few handy controls like Bold, Italics, Link, H2, H3 and Blockquote. I'd like to remove Htags (h2 and h3) as seen in the screenshot. I'm not sure how to go about achieving this.

[image: Tiny MCE Editor]

Here is how do the initialization:

```
$.fn.initTiny = function(selector, data, mode){
    var this_mode = mode ? mode : "";       
    this_mode = this_mode == "inline";
    tinymce.init({
      selector: selector, 
      inline: this_mode,
      placeholder: 'Type here...',
      menubar: true,
      statusbar: false,
      toolbar: true,
      toolbar_mode: 'scrolling',
      plugins: 'lists searchreplace preview image importcss autoresize searchreplace  powerpaste autolink  directionality code visualblocks visualchars fullscreen  link  table charmap hr insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount imagetools textpattern noneditable charmap quickbars emoticons',
      toolbar: ' undo redo  |  fontselect | fontsizeselect |  bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent numlist bullist',
      advlist_bullet_styles: 'default,circle,disc,square',
      fontsize_formats: '8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 24pt 36pt 48pt',
      paste_data_images: true,

      autoresize_on_init: true,
      min_height: 400,
      setup: function (editor) {
          editor.on('init', function (e) {
            editor.setContent(data);
          });
          editor.on("focusout",function(){
                $.fn.save_data();
          });
      }

    });
};
```

Also is that option called context menu?

Have any of you had this scenario before - would love to hear your thoughts....

Comment: Interestingly when I set contextmenu=false, it still was appearing

Answer (score 0):

Got it.It is called as [Quick Toolbar](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/quickbars/)

This is how I fixed it

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'div.tinymce',
  plugins: 'quickbars',
  quickbars_selection_toolbar: true,
  quickbars_selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | formatselect | quicklink   blockquote'
});
```